# Deleting multiple columns in M-scripts if they have all the same value

Tags: powerquery, m

I just started with M-scripts.
Do you know how to create a query where all columns with the same value are deleted?

I have already managed to create a script for a single column, but I don't get much further.

Can I apply the code to all columns with an M-function, or is there maybe another function/object in M for it?

Greetings

Markus

[image]

```
let
    Source= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Überschrift 1", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 2", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 3", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 4", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 5", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 6", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 7", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 8", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 9", Int64.Type}, {"Überschrift 10", Int64.Type}}),

//List wit all Column names
        column_names = 
                Table.ColumnNames( #"Changed Type" ),
        column_max = 
                List.Count(column_names ),

//How many Different Column values are in the Column / List ? 
        different_column_values =
                List.Count(
                    List.Distinct(
                         Table.Column( #"Changed Type" , column_names  {1}))),

//Delete the column if there is not more than 1 different value:    
        delete_column = 
            (if
               different_column_values = 1
            then
                Table.RemoveColumns(  #"Changed Type"  , column_names  {1})
            else
            false
            )    

in 

delete_column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single step:

```
= Table.RemoveColumns(Source, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each List.Count(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,_))) = 1 ))
```

This counts the distinct values in each column, and removes columns which only contain 1 distinct value.